# How the dependency is getting injected in spring when object is created with new operator?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection

I have a `CustomerRelation` class which has a method `getInstance()` and  instance variable i.e

```
private CustomerCrudService relationshipService = null;
```

Brief about the `getInstance` method is

```
 static public CustomerRelation getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = new customerRelation();//line1
     }
 return instance;//line2
   }
```

Now  i put the the debugger at line 1. After executing this line,i see instance is created containing relationshipService
object. My question is how dependency relationshipService got injected while creating the instance with new operator?

Though in MyProject-SpringConfig.xml i can see below configuration but still how the event , when we are creating the object
with new operator, is getting intercepted by spring core container? Is it because of spring customclassloader. If yes
where do we specify this?

```
  <bean class="com.its.portfolio.relationship.CustomerRelation" scope="prototype">
    <property name="relationshipService" ref="relationshipService" />
  </bean>
```

**Edit:-** Here is the code of CustomerRelation

```
    package com.its.relationship;

    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;

    /**
     * accessor for customerrelation meta data
     *
     */
    @Configurable
    public class CustomerRelation implements ICustomerRelation {

      static private CustomerRelation instance;
      private ICustomerRelationshipCrudService relationshipService;

      private CustomerRelation() {
      }

      static public ICustomerRelation getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
          instance = new CustomerRelation();
        }
        return instance;
      }

    }
```

Comment: Show us the code for `customerRelation`, as well as the rest of the config

Comment: And please call your class `CustomerRelation` with a capital `C`.

Comment: That seems fishy to me. Don't you have `factory-method="getInstance"` defined for your spring bean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how the event , when we are creating the object with new operator, is getting intercepted by spring core container?

It happens due to this bit of magic:

```
@Configurable
```

As you suspected, this uses a custom classloader (and load-time AOP weaving) to [inject dependencies into your domain object](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable) on-the-fly.

Comment: After going thru the link you mentioned, its a kind of marker interface in this way, Spring will configure new instances of the annotated type . Agreed with @Configurable 
, we have marked it to be configured by spring. In annotation source code i dont see any stuff related to custom class loader. I am not getting how with and at what point of time this marker interface information will be processed?

Comment: i mean this annotation at some point of time need to be processed by some spring java class. I am not sure at what point of time it will be processed as with new operator control will go the application classloader and it will create the as usual instance. Where will spring class will chip in to process this annotation?

Comment: @MSach: I posted a documentation link that explains how it works.

Comment: You can do the same with an AspectJ compiler, instead of AOP load time weaving (But you need to compile that class).

Answer (score 1):

Put an `@Inject` or `@Resourse` annotation to the field declaration.

```
@Resourse
private ICustomerRelationshipCrudService relationshipService;
```

Enable `@Configurable` support

And use AspectJ

- @See [Spring Reference: 3.9 Annotation-based container configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-annotation-config)
- @See Spring Reference: 7.8.1 Using AspectJ to dependency inject domain objects with Spring